# Word Office JS Addin - GET Request - Object doesn't support property or method 'apply'

Tags: javascript, ajax, ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I'm trying to get some data from a Web API through a Word Office JavaScript addin using an ajax request. However, I am getting the following error when I make the call:

**0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'apply'**

Here is my code:

```
Office.onReady(function () {
        // Office is ready
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // The document is ready
            // Use this to check whether the API is supported in the Word client.
            if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', '1.1')) {

                $('#rooms').click(Word.run(function (context) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost/soundtestingsoftware/public/api/projects/27/rooms",
                        type: "GET",
                        success: function (result) {
                            var doc = context.document.getSelection();
                            doc.insertText(JSON.stringify(result), Word.InsertLocation.start);
                            return context.sync();
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });
                }));

                $('#supportedVersion').html('This code is using Word 2016 or later.');
            }
            else {
                // Just letting you know that this code will not work with your version of Word.
                $('#supportedVersion').html('This code requires Word 2016 or later.');
            }
        });
    });
```

I've added my AppDomain into the manifest file. Could someone tell me why this error is happening please? Thanks

Comment: Are you seeing this error in the `error` callback? Also, try adding the port to `http://localhost` and try using https instead of http.

Comment: @RickKirkham I have fixed this error by including the latest jquery cdn in my Home.html file. Now the code runs without an error but my ajax request is not working as it is not retrieving any data from the server. Nothing happens when I run the code. I have added the port to http://localhost but no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: Use the Fiddler tool to see the Request and Response for the $.ajax call.

Comment: @RickKirkham In Fiddler I get a 200 reponse and it returns the JSON I am expecting. However, nothing is happening. This runs in Fiddler when i run the program and not when I click the '#rooms' button in the UI

Comment: Your code is calling the `Word.run` function instead of assigning it to the click event. Please encapsulate the `Word.run` into a named function and then assign the function name to the click event. See the samples in the [Script Lab](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380862?tab=Overview) tool for examples.